# Not understanding how factory pattern works

Tags: php, oop, factory

I have created an abstract factory class that includes a method storing in an array all the objects the factory creates.

```
abstract class ItemFactory{

   function __construct($default_item){

       $this->default_item = $default_item;
   }

   // Returns a new item + add the item to the factory items collection
   function createFactoryItem(){

       $this->addFactoryItem($object = clone $this->default_item);

       return $object;
   }

   // Add the item to the collection of items created with the factory
   function addFactoryItem($item_obj){

       $this->items[] = $item_obj;

       return $this;
   }
}
```

The class ElementFactory extends ItemFactory and so does SubElement.

```
class ElementFactory extends ItemFactory{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(new Element(new SubElement())));
    }
}
```

I am currently baffled by the behavior of this factory pattern in the example below.

```
$element_factory = new ElementFactory();

$element_factory->createFactoryItem()->setElementId(1);

$element_factory->createFactoryItem()->setElementId(2);

// Here I create a variable that stores the third element created from the factory
// setElementId() method belongs to Element and return $this
$element_3 = $element_factory->createFactoryItem()->setElementId(3);

// Here the part creating weird results
$element_3->getSubElementFactory()->createFactoryItem();

var_dump($element_factory);
```

What I expected was something like this:

```
ElementFactory Items:
Array
[0]: Element 1
[1]: Element 2
[2]: Element 3
     '-- [0] : SubElement 1

Instead I get this:
[0]: Element 1
     '-- [0] : SubElement 1
[1]: Element 2
     '-- [0] : SubElement 1
[2]: Element 3
     '-- [0] : SubElement 1
```

I have created a separate variable to store the third object created by the factory and the method getSubElementFactory()->createFactoryItem() is called for the third element only: **why the SubElement object is still added to ALL the elements of the factory in the third one only**?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is less of a factory and more of a collection.

That being said I think your problem does not lie in the pattern, but rather in the clone.

In PHP, [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) is not a deep copy.

Based on the sample provided for `ElementFactory` you are probably setting the `SubElement` as a Member Variable of the Element class.

This clone does not follow this link and create a new copy of the sub element. It will create a new copy of the element, but the copy will copy over the pointer to the same `SubElement` as the original.

This means that calling `getSubElementFactory` on one is the same as calling it on another. Thus creating the illusion of three copies.

What you can do is to add a `__clone` method to your class. This method would have to create a new `SubElement`. (Clone it also?).

This will provide the desired behaviour.

Comment: Many thanks for this great insight, I have added `function __clone(){ $this->default_item = clone $this->default_item; return $this->default_item; }` in ElementFactory yet the end result is the same, am I implementing the deep copy properly?

Comment: Nevermind, I set up __clone in the factory instead of setting it up in the item  class the factory makes. Many thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: The __clone method is what allows the author to write the deep copy algorithm. Or at-least helps to standardize such code.